# App com HTML, formulário automático

Tags: php, html, jquery, formulário, app

os apps com html são funcionais? Estou tentando criar um e tenho um formulário onde se define um contato da agenda, uma mensagem pré definida e quando clicar no botão, automaticamente essa mensagem será enviada para o contato. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Sim, são funcionais. Para o pessoal lhe auxiliar, é necessário um **[mcve]**, assim fica mais fácil de ajuda-lo.

Comment: Também gostaria de ter